# How to find the direction of normal force in fluids?

Tags: forces, fluid-dynamics, flow

[image]

is it gonna be in this direction or ????
I read couple of books and many say it is in the below direction shown

[image]

Comment: please dont mind the bad drawing

Comment: Which book has the 2nd diagram? Maybe you interpreted the diagram wrong. If the walls are inclined at an obtuse angle to the base of the container then the normal force acts like shown in the 2nd diagram.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A *normal* force is a force that is **perpendicular to a surface**. Consider the following irregularly shaped bottle, filled with a fluid:

[image: Normal forces]

All the red arrows are *normal forces* because they're all perpendicular to some surface.

Pressure $P$ is defined as:

$$P=\frac{F}{A}$$

where $F$ is the force and $A$ is the surface area the force act upon, so:

$$F=P\times A$$

Note that due to Newton's 3rd, these forces beget an equal but opposite reaction.

Comment: It probably would have been better to do what the OP did and show the reaction force of the wall on the fluid.  He may have been more able to relate to this.

Comment: @ChetMiller    I'll add a note to that effect.